# Skype for web sdk signin issue with on prem use case

Tags: skype-for-business

I am trying your samples and some very simple code for signing in. Status changes to Signing In. But it stays there and doesn't go to Signed In.

```
Following is my code :


var config = {
apiKey: 'a42fcebd-5b43-4b89-a065-74450fb91255', // SDK
apiKeyCC: '9c967f6b-a846-4df2-b43d-5167e47d81e1' // SDK+UI
};

var client;

$(function () {
'use strict';

Skype.initialize({ apiKey: config.apiKey }, function (api) {
     client = new api.application();

     // whenever client.state changes, display its value
     client.signInManager.state.changed(function (state) {
          $('p').text("Status : "+state);
     });

 }, function (err) {
     console.log(err);
     alert('Cannot load the SDK.');
 });

 $('#LogIn').click(function () {

    // start signing in
    client.signInManager.signIn({
      username: $('#username').val(),
      password: $('#password').val()
    }).then(function () {
        //log in worked!
        $('p').text("Status : "+"Logged In");
      }, function (error) {
        //Something went wrong.
        $('p').text("Status : "+error);
      });
  });
```

I installed Skype for Business desktop client and used same username and password and could sign in successfully. But with the above code, I am unable to sign in. Its staying at "signing In". I am not getting errors also. I also used your samples as per this article : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/downloadrunsamples

But I saw the same issue. The spinning wheel is forever spinning. It looks like it is looking at the same status as my code and staying at signing in.

Please let me know what wrong I might be doing. Just starting with this SDK. Any suggestions for debugging also can help.

[image: Signing In with a progress bar]

Comment: You should bring up developer tools, via F12, and check the console log and/or network trace  to see what the response to the requests.  I would suspect you would find a X-Ms-Diagnostic header similar to: X-Ms-diagnostics: 28070;source="...";reason="Service does not allow a cross domain request from this origin."

Comment: I used firefox to debug the request and response. The response is empty. But I am suspecting cross domain authorization to be the issue. Working on it.

Comment: If you are having CORS problems you may need to add to the allowed domain list. See this article: https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/ITAdmin-Configuration